# Why is my solution for the final Keep puzzle incorrect?

Tags: the-witness

I tried solving the puzzle at the Keep overlooking the glass walking maze area, and I came up with a solution that appears to satisfy all of the constraints:

[image: Keep puzzle solution]

The game doesn't accept it though. What am I doing wrong? What is the actual solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You mirrored one of the tilted tetromino pieces in the bottom left. You can only rotate them:

[image]

Here's a correct solution (you were close!)

> [image]
>
>  The 'L' shaped piece should match the light blue 'L' shaped piece as shown in the previously completed puzzles behind the panel.